# I got an API on AWS how to post json data using django?

Tags: python, json, django, rest, api

It is working fine when I pass data from POSTMAN. I just want to call the API from Django the same as we do in the postman.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not a django expert but you can look into a library like [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/). In postman there’s an option to select code and you should be able to scroll to select python and see the options there. I’m not sure if that answers your question. If you’re looking to build a gui like postman using django you would have to setup the app and maybe a button underneath that would make a request using requests or some other library.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could call http service using urllib, it is python built in library you don't have to install anything almost every features are there and there is also a third party http library alternative to urllib called [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) with comprehensive features, which also uses urllib behind scene, it would be overkill just for calling simple http endpoint but it makes the life so easier BTW.

There will be no different calling from django, you can just wrap it under the view.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('http://example.com') as res:
    print(res.read())  # get request

# for post request with headers
from urllib.request import Request

req = Request(headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, url='http://example.com', data='{"name": "Someone"}'.encode())

with urlopen(req) as res:
    print(res.read())  # preform post request
```